# Why my code compare only first and last number of array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, random, min

I want to get the minimum number of my array, but my "if" compare only checks the first and last positions of array.

Here is my code:

```java
int[] randNumbers = new int[20]; //deklaracja nowej tablicy 20-elementowej

Random r = new Random(); // Dodana metoda random do losowania

for(int i=0; i<randNumbers.length; i++) {
    randNumbers[i] = r.nextInt(101);
    int min = randNumbers[0];

    System.out.println("Number "+i+": " +  randNumbers[i]);


    if (randNumbers[i] < min) {
        min = randNumbers[i];
    }
    if (i == randNumbers.length-1) {
        System.out.println("Min number is: " + min);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need the array here. Just iterate from 0 to `N` and check each random number if it less than min:

```
Random r = new Random();
int min = 101;    // assign max value 101 before loop

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    int number = r.nextInt(101);
    System.out.println("Number " + i + ": " +  number);
    if (number < min) {
        min = number;
    }
}
System.out.println(min);
```

If you want use array, you could initialize it before. For example using [`Random.ints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-):

```
int[] randNumbers = new Random().ints(20, 0, 101).toArray();
```

And then use the same `for-loop` idea with `randNumbers[i]` instead of `nextInt(101)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not remembering the minimum number as the loop runs. If you make a variable outside of the loop, it won't get updated every single iteration. Your code might look something like this:

```java
int[] randNumbers = new int[20]; //deklaracja nowej tablicy 20-elementowej
Random r = new Random(); // Dodana metoda random do losowania
int min = 0;

for(int i=0; i<randNumbers.length; i++) {
    int number = r.nextInt(101);
    if(i == 0) min = number;
    randNumbers[i] = number;
    System.out.println("Number "+i+": " + number);

    min = Math.min(min, number);
}

System.out.println("Min number is: " + min);
```

A few things to notice:

- The variable `min` was moved outside of the loop. This is to make sure it is persistent across the loop, and won't be updated every iteration of the loop.
- A new variable `number` is introduced. This is to prevent you from constantly calling `randNumbers[i]`, which looks nicer, and to my knowledge slightly speeds it up. It also make it easier to change the variable once, and have it effective everywhere it is needed.
- The last `S.O.P` was moved outside of the loop. There is no point in checking if the loop is at the last element if you can just put the statement the line after the loop ends. It will work the same functionally, but this looks nicer.
- Instead of using an `if` statement to set min, it uses the output of `Math.min`. This is just a cosmetic change, and behaves the exact same with an `if` statement.

Comment: At line 3 `int min = randNumbers[0]`, `randNumber[0]` hasn't been assigned a meaningful value yet. So the assignment of that uninitialized value to min would probably alter the validity of the result...

Comment: @geneSummons completely forgot about that! Thanks for picking up on it :)

Comment: Also, as mentioned in other answers, the "standard" way to search for a minimum value in a collection is to start with the maximum possible value as your default minimum value.  So, `int min = Integer.MAX_INT` would be a more idiomatic default minimum value than zero.

Comment: ^This is a solution what i looked for. Very thanks :) @geneSummons
Didn't know about option with   int min=Integer.Max_Int

Comment: @Hugoniasty  My bad, per Javadocs, the static field is actually `Integer.MAX_VALUE` not `MAX_INT`

Answer (score 0):

try this out, your `int min = randNumbers[0];` resets the min value every time so move it out of the loop

```
int min = 100;
for(int i=0; i<randNumbers.length; i++) {
    randNumbers[i] = r.nextInt(101);
    System.out.println("Number "+i+": " +  randNumbers[i]);
    if (randNumbers[i] < min) {
          min = randNumbers[i];
    }
}
System.out.println("Min number is: " + min);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Move min int outside loop with value 0 isn't working, because my result will be everytime because Not initialized array have only '0'
2. Move it with 100+ is good idea. It's working when we know maximum number.
3. @geneSummons "int min = Integer.MAX_INT"
   This works very well with different range/scope of numbers:) Thanks

Btw. I still don't understand why it's compare only first and last number ;)

Comment: `if (randNumbers[i] < min)` compares every `i` indexed value against the minimum value, not just first and last.  What exactly don't you understand?  Have you stepped through your code using a debugger?